# Python Django: How to pass model's data to Admin default start page (index.html)?

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a Python Django application and would like to build a kind of dashboard on the ADMIN startpage/defaultpage (index.html). For this purpose I want to display e.g. different data of my models.

I have tried to access the data of my models outside the admin area and to display them as I like. It worked there. However, it did not work with the same code in the admin area on the default startpage.

I don't know how to access my models/objects in the index.html/Admin startpage.

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom template [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) like this:

```
# file: my_app/context_processors/dashboard.py

def dashboard(request):
    return {'model1': Model1.objects.all(), 'model2': Model2.objects.all(), ... }
```

And add it to `context_processors` section inside `TEMPLATES`:

```
'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            # rest of the processors
            'my_app.context_processors.dashboard'
        ],
 }
```

Finally, use it anywhere in admin site templates:

```
{% for model in model1 %}
    {{ model.pk }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Therefore I have to create a new template 'dashboard' and insert it into my view 'index.html', right?

Comment: no, you just have to loop through the context variables to access the queryset.

Comment: I honestly thought that in the admin area the model data are available in the views without any hassle.

Comment: I'll try it out later and let you know. Thanks a lot!